# Dynamic max-height for div based on window size/resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

Coding/jQuery beginner here.

I am trying to figure out how to adjust the max height for a div, which is placed in between a top `'.top-nav'` and bottom `'.footer'` div, based on the screen size.  Basically, no scroll bar should appear when the page loads or the window is resized.

The div I need resized, `'.color-container'`, wraps a series of lists that changes to a random color when hovered over.  If I have enough list elements, I figured the max-height property for '.color-container' would cut them off at the appropriate location.

Based on my research I need to call the `.resize` function, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

My jQuery code:

```
function resetHeight(){
    var newHeight = $(window).height() - $('.top-nav').outerHeight() - $('.footer').outerHeight();
    $('.color-container').css('max-height', newHeight);
}

$(function(){
    newHeight();

    $(window).resize(function(){
      resetHeight();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgdude/2qsq725e/14/

Comment: You probably need to do `$(window).on('resize',function(){...})`

Comment: Working fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2qsq725e/17/)**. Your fiddle did not have reference to `jquery`. hope you have included it? and yea you need to call `resetHeight()` at begining and not `newHeight()`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao mentioned the 2 issues you need to fix. I didn't realize that .resize(...) was the same as .on('resize',...)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thank you so much!  `resetHeight()` instead of `newHeight()` was the issue.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the exact answer of the question,but I used `position: absolute;` in classes and I hope that helps you,please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2qsq725e/19/